# r replace missing values with a constant and column name follow a common pattern

Tags: r, missing-data, mode, imputation

My dataset has columns and values like this. The column names all start with a common string, Col_a_**

```
 ID    Col_a_01    Col_a_02    Col_a_03
 1     1           2           1
 2     1           NA          0
 3     NA          0           2
 4     1           0           1
 5     0           0           2
```

My goal is to replace the missing values with the mode values for that column.

The expected dataset to be like this

```
  ID    Col_a_01    Col_a_02    Col_a_03
  1     1           2           1
  2     1           0**         0
  3     1**         0           2
  4     1           0           1
  5     0           0           2
```

The NA in the first column is replaced by 1 because the mode of the 1st column is 1. The NA in the second column is replaced by 0 because the mode for the 2nd column is 0.

I can do this like this below

```
getmode <- function(v) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

 df$Col_a_01[is.na(Col_a_01)==TRUE] <- getmode(df$Col_a_01)
 df$Col_a_03[is.na(Col_a_02)==TRUE] <- getmode(df$Col_a_02)
 df$Col_a_03[is.na(Col_a_03)==TRUE] <- getmode(df$Col_a_03)
```

But this becomes unwieldy if I have 100 columns starting with the similar names ending in 1,2,3..100. I am curious if there is an easier and more elegant way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RonakShah, question updated with the mode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.aggregate` with `FUN` specified as `getmode`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('Col_a'), na.aggregate, FUN = getmode))
```

-output

```
df1
  ID Col_a_01 Col_a_02 Col_a_03
1  1        1        2        1
2  2        1        0        0
3  3        1        0        2
4  4        1        0        1
5  5        0        0        2
```

---

Or it can be simply

```
na.aggregate(df1, FUN = getmode)
ID Col_a_01 Col_a_02 Col_a_03
1  1        1        2        1
2  2        1        0        0
3  3        1        0        2
4  4        1        0        1
5  5        0        0        2
```

Comment: thanks. This worked, but something is strange with `starts_with` , it does not work if I go with `starts_with`, if I change this to `matches` then it works. Head scratcher.

Comment: @Science11 `matches` takes a regex pattern.So if there are any case that doesn't match or have metacharacter it may parse it differently.  `starts_with` is a fixed match So, you may have to check whether all the columns are named as `Col_` or not.

Comment: ah got it. There are some columns starting with the same string but ending in something like _dateTime, _ TI etc, like this Col_a_dateTime, Col_a_TI...

Comment: @Science11 The `starts_with` should match both of those because the prefix mentioned is `'Col_a'` or else there may be some leading/lagging spaces or other characters

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `NA` values with `ifelse`/`replace`, to apply a function to multiple columns use `across` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
       mutate(across(starts_with('Col_a'), ~replace(., is.na(.), getmode(.))))
```

In base R , use `lapply` -

```
cols <- grep('Col_a', names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), getmode(x)))
```

Comment: If you really want to debug the issue provide the data using `dput` because if I copy the data and use it I get data as `df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Col_a_01 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L), Col_a_02 = c(2L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), Col_a_03 = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))` and the answer works and I get the expected output.

Comment: I think this may be a cascade of errors on my end, more than anything else.